# How to create an Eureka AlertRow with options from Core Data and a "None" option?

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

GTDItemEntity is a Core Data entity. I need to be able to take "None" or "No Project" as a valid value. I can do that with .value and .displayValueFor. But how do I allow it in the options?

```
 <<< AlertRow<GTDItemEntity>() {
            $0.title = "Project"
            $0.value = self.item?.project
            $0.displayValueFor = { project in
                return project?.text ?? "No Project"
            }
            $0.options = [nil] // sample one option with nil value
            $0.onChange() {
                self.item.project = $0.value
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to change to a `AlertRow<GTDItemEntity?>`:

```
 <<< AlertRow<GTDItemEntity>() {
            $0.title = "Project"
            $0.value = self.item?.project
            $0.displayValueFor = { project in
                return project??.text ?? "No Project" // *
            }
            $0.options = [nil] // sample one option with nil value
            $0.onChange() {
                self.item.project = $0.value ?? nil // *
            }
        }
```

Note that this makes `$0.value` a double optional, which is why I changed some code in the lines marked with `*`.

Another way to do this would be to add a special `GTDItemEntity` as one of the options. You would assign a value to a certain field of this special `GTDItemEntity` such that no other `GTDItemEntity` has that value. Then, you can check if the value of the row has changed to that special entity in `onChange`. If it did, set the value to nil.